# Why can`t I connect to Windows Azure VM running couchbase with public IP using java .. Getting Connection time out error?

Tags: java, azure, memcached, couchbase, httpconnection

I am trying to connect to my virtual machines in Azure cloud havng couchbase installed on it and all the ports as required by couchbase to be open. I am able to ping those machines.
Suppose my machine on azure has ip 1.2.3.4:8091. This VM has 3 nodes having IP 192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
192.168.0.6

When I give this ip in my java runtime parameters to connect to the machine using org.apache.http jar it gets converted to the internal private IP address eg: 192.168.0.4:8091 but then I get a connection timed out error. Why? Is there no way I can conect to a remote server using java without getting a timeout? Do I always have to deploy the app on that cluster locally?

```
 Oct 31, 2013 2:25:11 AM com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseProperties setPropertyFile
    FINE: Could not load properties file "cbclient.properties" because: File not found with system classloader.
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:11 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP readToString
    FINE: Attempting to read configuration from URI: http://1.2.3.4:8091/pools
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:11 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP readToString
    FINE: Attempting to read configuration from URI: http://1.2.3.4:8091/pools/default?uuid=29ee39bf4f6daf0de614e85aacf00ac4
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:11 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP readToString
    FINE: Attempting to read configuration from URI: http://1.2.3.4:8091/pools/default/buckets?v=121918534&uuid=29ee39bf4f6daf0de614e85aacf00ac4
```

Here we can clearly see in this bottom part that it gets connected to the bucket gets the HTTP data but then says connection timedout.

```
        Oct 31, 2013 2:25:36 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection queueReconnect
WARNING: Closing, and reopening {QA sa=192.168.0.4/192.168.0.4:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}, attempt 1.
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:36 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection handleIO
FINE: Done dealing with queue.
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:36 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection handleIO
FINE: Selecting with delay of 3985ms
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:40 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection handleIO
FINE: No selectors ready, interrupted: false
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:40 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection attemptReconnects
INFO: Reconnecting {QA sa=192.168.0.6/192.168.0.6:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:40 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection handleIO
FINE: Done dealing with queue.
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:40 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection handleIO
FINE: Selecting with delay of 1ms
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:40 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection handleIO
FINE: No selectors ready, interrupted: false
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:40 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection attemptReconnects
INFO: Reconnecting {QA sa=192.168.0.5/192.168.0.5:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:40 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection handleIO
FINE: Done dealing with queue.
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:40 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection handleIO
FINE: Selecting with delay of 3ms
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:40 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection handleIO
FINE: No selectors ready, interrupted: false
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:40 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection attemptReconnects
INFO: Reconnecting {QA sa=192.168.0.4/192.168.0.4:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:40 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection handleIO
FINE: Done dealing with queue.
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:40 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection handleIO
FINE: Selecting with delay of 0ms
30 Seconds:  Load is in progress
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:42 AM com.couchbase.client.ViewConnection createConnections
INFO: Added 192.168.0.6 to connect queue
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:48 AM com.couchbase.client.ViewConnection createConnections
INFO: Added 192.168.0.5 to connect queue
40 Seconds:  Load is in progress
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:52 AM com.couchbase.client.ViewConnection createConnections
INFO: Added 192.168.0.4 to connect queue
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:52 AM com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient <init>
INFO: viewmode property isn't defined. Setting viewmode to production mode
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:52 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP subscribe
FINE: Subscribing an object for reconfiguration updates com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:52 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler handleUpstream
FINEST: Channel state changed: [id: 0x1fea8fc0] OPEN


Oct 31, 2013 2:25:52 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler handleUpstream
FINER: Channel state change is not a disconnect. Event value is true and Channel State is OPEN.
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:52 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler handleUpstream
FINEST: Channel state changed: [id: 0x1fea8fc0, /192.168.0.10:15658 => /1.2.3.4:8091:8091] BOUND: /192.168.0.10:15658


Oct 31, 2013 2:25:52 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler handleUpstream
FINER: Channel state change is not a disconnect. Event value is /192.168.0.10:15658 and Channel State is BOUND.
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:52 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler handleUpstream
FINEST: Channel state changed: [id: 0x1fea8fc0, /192.168.0.10:15658 => /1.2.3.4:8091:8091] CONNECTED: /1.2.3.4:8091:8091


Oct 31, 2013 2:25:52 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler handleUpstream
FINER: Channel state change is not a disconnect. Event value is /1.2.3.4:8091:8091 and Channel State is CONNECTED.
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler finerLog
FINER: STATUS: 200 OK
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler finerLog
FINER: VERSION: HTTP/1.1
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler finerLog
FINER: HEADER: Cache-Control = no-cache
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler finerLog
FINER: HEADER: Content-Type = application/json; charset=utf-8
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler finerLog
FINER: HEADER: Date = Thu, 31 Oct 2013 09:25:51 GMT
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler finerLog
FINER: HEADER: Pragma = no-cache
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler finerLog
FINER: HEADER: Server = Couchbase Server 2.2.0-821-rel-enterprise
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler finerLog
FINER: HEADER: Transfer-Encoding = chunked
Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler finerLog
FINER: 

    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler finerLog
    FINER: CHUNKED CONTENT {
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler finerLog
    FINER: {"name":"users","bucketType":"membase","authType":"sasl","saslPassword":"","proxyPort":0,"replicaIndex":false,"uri":"/pools/default/buckets/users?bucket_uuid=3cfaca6ceb99782a74bbc52df98aaba3","streamingUri":"/pools/default/bucketsStreaming/users?bucket_uuid=3cfaca6ceb99782a74bbc52df98aaba3","localRandomKeyUri":"/pools/default/buckets/users/localRandomKey","controllers":{"flush":"/pools/default/buckets/users/controller/doFlush","compactAll":"/pools/default/buckets/users/controller/compactBucket","compactDB":"/pools/default/buckets/default/controller/compactDatabases","purgeDeletes":"/pools/default/buckets/users/controller/unsafePurgeBucket","startRecovery":"/pools/default/buckets/users/controller/startRecovery"},"nodes":[{"couchApiBase":"http://192.168.0.6:8092/users","replication":1.0,"clusterMembership":"active","status":"healthy","otpNode":"ns_1@192.168.0.6","hostname":"192.168.0.6:8091","clusterCompatibility":131072,"version":"2.2.0-821-rel-enterprise","os":"windows","ports":{"proxy":11211,"direct":11210}},{"couchApiBase":"http://192.168.0.5:8092/users","replication":1.0,"clusterMembership":"active","status":"healthy","otpNode":"ns_1@192.168.0.5","hostname":"192.168.0.5:8091","clusterCompatibility":131072,"version":"2.2.0-821-rel-enterprise","os":"windows","ports":{"proxy":11211,"direct":11210}},{"couchApiBase":"http://192.168.0.4:8092/users","replication":1.0,"clusterMembership":"active","status":"healthy","otpNode":"ns_1@192.168.0.4","thisNode":true,"hostname":"192.168.0.4:8091","clusterCompatibility":131072,"version":"2.2.0-821-rel-enterprise","os":"windows","ports":{"proxy":11211,"direct":11210}}],"stats":{"uri":"/pools/default/buckets/users/stats","directoryURI":"/pools/default/buckets/users/statsDirectory","nodeStatsListURI":"/pools/default/buckets/users/nodes"},"ddocs":{"uri":"/pools/default/buckets/users/ddocs"},"nodeLocator":"vbucket","fastWarmupSettings":false,"autoCompactionSettings":false,"uuid":"3cfaca6ceb99782a74bbc52df98aaba3","vBucketServerMap":{"hashAlgorithm":"CRC","numReplicas":0,"serverList":["192.168.0.4:11210","192.168.0.5:11210","192.168.0.6:11210"],"vBucketMap":[[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]]},"bucketCapabilitiesVer":"","bucketCapabilities":["touch","couchapi"]}
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketUpdateResponseHandler finerLog
    FINER: Chunk length is: 6293
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ReconfigurableObserver update
    FINEST: Received an update, notifying reconfigurables about a com.couchbase.client.vbucket.config.Bucketcom.couchbase.client.vbucket.config.Bucket@e723c25e
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ReconfigurableObserver update
    FINEST: It says it is users and it's talking to /pools/default/bucketsStreaming/users?bucket_uuid=3cfaca6ceb99782a74bbc52df98aaba3
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection reconfigure
    FINE: Node 192.168.0.6/192.168.0.6:11210 will stay in cluster config after reconfiguration.
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.BucketMonitor logFiner
    FINER: Getting server list returns this last chunked response:
    {"name":"users","bucketType":"membase","authType":"sasl","saslPassword":"","proxyPort":0,"replicaIndex":false,"uri":"/pools/default/buckets/users?bucket_uuid=3cfaca6ceb99782a74bbc52df98aaba3","streamingUri":"/pools/default/bucketsStreaming/users?bucket_uuid=3cfaca6ceb99782a74bbc52df98aaba3","localRandomKeyUri":"/pools/default/buckets/users/localRandomKey","controllers":{"flush":"/pools/default/buckets/users/controller/doFlush","compactAll":"/pools/default/buckets/users/controller/compactBucket","compactDB":"/pools/default/buckets/default/controller/compactDatabases","purgeDeletes":"/pools/default/buckets/users/controller/unsafePurgeBucket","startRecovery":"/pools/default/buckets/users/controller/startRecovery"},"nodes":[{"couchApiBase":"http://192.168.0.6:8092/users","replication":1.0,"clusterMembership":"active","status":"healthy","otpNode":"ns_1@192.168.0.6","hostname":"192.168.0.6:8091","clusterCompatibility":131072,"version":"2.2.0-821-rel-enterprise","os":"windows","ports":{"proxy":11211,"direct":11210}},{"couchApiBase":"http://192.168.0.5:8092/users","replication":1.0,"clusterMembership":"active","status":"healthy","otpNode":"ns_1@192.168.0.5","hostname":"192.168.0.5:8091","clusterCompatibility":131072,"version":"2.2.0-821-rel-enterprise","os":"windows","ports":{"proxy":11211,"direct":11210}},{"couchApiBase":"http://192.168.0.4:8092/users","replication":1.0,"clusterMembership":"active","status":"healthy","otpNode":"ns_1@192.168.0.4","thisNode":true,"hostname":"192.168.0.4:8091","clusterCompatibility":131072,"version":"2.2.0-821-rel-enterprise","os":"windows","ports":{"proxy":11211,"direct":11210}}],"stats":{"uri":"/pools/default/buckets/users/stats","directoryURI":"/pools/default/buckets/users/statsDirectory","nodeStatsListURI":"/pools/default/buckets/users/nodes"},"ddocs":{"uri":"/pools/default/buckets/users/ddocs"},"nodeLocator":"vbucket","fastWarmupSettings":false,"autoCompactionSettings":false,"uuid":"3cfaca6ceb99782a74bbc52df98aaba3","vBucketServerMap":{"hashAlgorithm":"CRC","numReplicas":0,"serverList":["192.168.0.4:11210","192.168.0.5:11210","192.168.0.6:11210"],"vBucketMap":[[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]]},"bucketCapabilitiesVer":"","bucketCapabilities":["touch","couchapi"]}
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection reconfigure
    FINE: Node 192.168.0.5/192.168.0.5:11210 will stay in cluster config after reconfiguration.
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection reconfigure
    FINE: Node 192.168.0.4/192.168.0.4:11210 will stay in cluster config after reconfiguration.
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.VBucketNodeLocator updateLocator
    FINE: Received updated configuration with insignificant changes.
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ReconfigurableObserver update
    FINEST: Received an update, notifying reconfigurables about a com.couchbase.client.vbucket.config.Bucketcom.couchbase.client.vbucket.config.Bucket@f727c0e2
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ReconfigurableObserver update
    FINEST: It says it is users and it's talking to /pools/default/bucketsStreaming/users?bucket_uuid=3cfaca6ceb99782a74bbc52df98aaba3
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection reconfigure
    FINE: Node 192.168.0.6/192.168.0.6:11210 will stay in cluster config after reconfiguration.
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection reconfigure
    FINE: Node 192.168.0.5/192.168.0.5:11210 will stay in cluster config after reconfiguration.
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection reconfigure
    FINE: Node 192.168.0.4/192.168.0.4:11210 will stay in cluster config after reconfiguration.
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.VBucketNodeLocator updateLocator
    FINE: Received updated configuration with insignificant changes.
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:53 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP readToString
    FINE: Attempting to read configuration from URI: http://1.2.3.4:8091:8091/pools
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:55 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP readToString
    FINE: Attempting to read configuration from URI: http://1.2.3.4:8091:8091/pools/default?uuid=29ee39bf4f6daf0de614e85aacf00ac4
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:58 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP readToString
    FINE: Attempting to read configuration from URI: http://1.2.3.4:8091:8091/pools/default/buckets?v=121918534&uuid=29ee39bf4f6daf0de614e85aacf00ac4
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:58 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection createConnections
    INFO: Added {QA sa=/192.168.0.4:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:58 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection createConnections
    INFO: Added {QA sa=/192.168.0.5:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:58 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection createConnections
    INFO: Added {QA sa=/192.168.0.6:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
    Oct 31, 2013 2:25:58 AM com.couchbase.client.vbucket.VBucketNodeLocator fillNodesEntries
    FINE: Updating nodesMap in VBucketNodeLocator.
    50 Seconds:  Load is in progress
    Oct 31, 2013 2:26:01 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection handleIO
    FINE: Selected 1, selected 1 keys
    Oct 31, 2013 2:26:01 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection handleIO
    FINE: Handling IO for:  sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@45f76fc7 (r=false, w=false, c=true, op={QA sa=192.168.0.6/192.168.0.6:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=8})
    Oct 31, 2013 2:26:01 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection handleIO
    INFO: Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@45f76fc7
    Oct 31, 2013 2:26:01 AM net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection handleIO
    INFO: Reconnecting due to failure to connect to {QA sa=192.168.0.6/192.168.0.6:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:692)
        at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:423)
        at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:261)
        at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection.run(CouchbaseConnection.java:288)
```

I also tweaked the SO_timeout and Connection_timeout values for org.apache.http.params but nothing works. Is there no way I can connect to a remote server via Java client on remote machine? Also, the same public ip 1.2.3.4:8091 works on browser

Answer (score 0):

Please note that port 11210 is not reachable, not 8091.

Make sure that 11210, 8091 and 8092 are reachable and the hostnames are properly mapped.